# Spacing off in Achievements pull down menu on mobile web

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, mobile-web, achievements-dialog

I'm seeing a spacing issue under Achievements on iOS mobile Safari:

[image: Safari]

Is this a know issue?

- Device: iPhone 6
- OS Version: Version 9.1 (Build 13B143)